# Create a function that shows user controls in a panel

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I created several user controls that i want to display on a  main panel.
Thus, I have this function that takes in input the control I want to display by setting it to visible, and visible = false for all other ones :

```
Public Sub ShowControl(ByVal Controle As Control)
    MainPanel.BringToFront()
    Try
        With MainPanel
            For Each contr As Control In .Controls
                If contr.Name <> Controle.Name Then
                    contr.Visible = False
                Else
                    ' Display the control
                    contr.Visible = True
                End If
            Next

        End With

    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
```

It works well when my panel has different user controls like this :

```
            Public WithEvents uc1 As New User_Control1
        Public WithEvents uc2 As New User_Control2
        Public WithEvents uc3 As New User_Control3

        MainPanel.Controls.Add(uc1)
        MainPanel.Controls.Add(uc2)
        MainPanel.Controls.Add(uc3)
```

But not if I create several instances from the same user control :

```
            Public WithEvents uc1 As New User_Control1
        Public WithEvents uc2 As New User_Control1
        Public WithEvents uc3 As New User_Control1

        MainPanel.Controls.Add(uc1)
        MainPanel.Controls.Add(uc2)
        MainPanel.Controls.Add(uc3)
```

I know that this is because in my function the name Controle.name will remain the same (User_Control1), but is there any way to make it works ?

Comment: You need to do a reference check. Replace everything in the `For Each` loop block with just `contr.Visible = If(contr Is Controle, True, False)`. Also, get rid of the `Try...Catch` block, why do you need one here? No use.

Comment: Or just `contr.Visible = contr Is Controle`.

Comment: Both snippets have the same problem, the Name property is not set.  Giving a control a name is a feature of the designer, it occurs when you drop the control on a form.  That's not happening here, you must give Name a value explicitly.  Simply use, say, Public WithEvents uc1 As New User_Control1 With {.Name = "Sales"}

Comment: Thanks ! Indeed that was very simple lol. I used try catch on many other functions but you're right this is not useful here